# Laravel - Calling my Web services Api multiple times bypass the logic of single entry in database and duplication record in database

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, transactions, mariadb

I've a web services Api 
Api inserts data multiple times in database while it has only to **insert only one time** and **update second time** If record exist.

The Problem occurring due to Transaction. I've brief all thing what's happening here.

Laravel 5.4
Database: Maria Db 10.1.21
Host: Localhost

web service Includes

- call external apis to fetch result
- store fetch result in database

// code here

```
   public function getWebsiteDetails(Request $request) {
    Log::info("call ");
    try 
    {
     return DB::transaction(function () use($request)  
    {

    //  Get record from website_master of given business id
    $businessWebsiteRecord = Website::where([
        'business_id' => $businessId
    ])->first();

    // calling external api to get result
    $pageSpeedResult = $this->pageSpeedResult($url);

    Log::info("crossed external api point");

    /**
     * Again check to confirm record is exist or not
     * code write to only for testing purpose
     */
    $recordChecker = Website::where
    (
        'business_id', $businessId
    )->first();

    if(!empty($recordChecker))
    {
    Log::info("if" );
    }
    else
    {
    Log::info("else");
    }

    /**
    * Update record if exist
    * else
    * Create record
    */
    Website::updateOrCreate(
    ['business_id' => $businessId],
    [
    'website' => $url
    ]
    );

    // saving data in another table after some operatins
    $thirdObj->globalIssueGenerator(/* some data*/);

    return $this->helpReturn('Website data saved & issues are generated in system');
    });

    } catch (Exception $e) {
    Log::info(" getWebsiteDetails >> " . $e->getMessage());
    return $this->helpError(1, 'Some Problem happened to run script.');
    }
    }
```

I've to add only single row entry in database table. But the problem is 
If I **call api multiple times** it **inserts data multiple times** in database **while it has only to add first/single time**. 
As Laravel `Updateorcreate` function is using.

**Test Case**

If I call APi first time and then again hit that api **second time after 3-5** seconds

That api will bypass the check and re-insert data like insert data in multiple times like shown in this screenshot.

[image]

That's why I using below code to check.

```
/**
* Again check to confirm record is exist or not
* code write to only for testing purpose
*/

$recordChecker = Website::where
('business_id', $businessId)->first();

if(!empty($recordChecker))
{
Log::info("if");
}
else
{
Log::info("else");
}
```

**Logs:**

so logs generated time same like in database insertion screenshot.

```
[2018-02-12 06:18:58] local.INFO: call   
[2018-02-12 06:19:03] local.INFO: call   
[2018-02-12 06:19:16] local.INFO: crossed external api point
```

**Going in else because data not available in database**

```
[2018-02-12 06:19:16] local.INFO: else
```

**like in screenshot data has been inserted in database.**

**Second Call logs**

```
[2018-02-12 06:19:19] local.INFO: else
[2018-02-12 06:19:19] local.INFO: crossed external api point
```

**Again Going in else because data has not been in database yet.**

### Data has been submitted in database but yet second call response is on the way

### **Problem Detected:**

**I'm using Transaction** 
I'm updating two tables by inserting/updating a record.

**Without Transaction**
If I comment transaction code and apply above mentioned test cases data insert only single time. What I require.

Here's the logs of without transaction

```
[2018-02-12 06:59:56] local.INFO: call   
[2018-02-12 07:00:00] local.INFO: call   
[2018-02-12 07:00:14] local.INFO: crossed external api point
```

**Going in else because data not available in database so data will be create**

```
[2018-02-12 07:00:14] local.INFO: else  

[2018-02-12 07:00:17] local.INFO: crossed external api point
```

Going in if because data available in database

```
[2018-02-12 07:00:17] local.INFO: if
```

But I can't remove transaction because after inserting data in first table most operation done and insert multiple data in table.

I'm thinking to use different action to handle to update flag in file system or in Redis but that's a different technique whichI'll handle this.

I want if any one has fix of this because I've more web services which I'm using same technique

FUll Code

```
public function getWebsiteDetails(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info("call ");
        try {
            return DB::transaction(function () use($request)
            {
                $thirdObj = new ThirdPartyEntity();

                // user extract
                $checkPoint = $this->setCurrentUser($request->get('token'))->userAllow();

                $user = $checkPoint['records'];
                $businessDetail = $this->businessEntity->userSelectedBusiness($user);

                $businessDetail = $businessDetail['records'];

                $userId = $user['id'];
                $businessId = $businessDetail['business_id'];
                $url = $businessDetail['website'];

                /**
                 * Get record from website_master of given business id
                 */
                $businessWebsiteRecord = Website::where([
                    'business_id' => $businessId
                ])->first();

                // if business_master (url) is exist then go to if block
                if ($url != '') {
                    $data = [];

                        $pageSpeedScore = '';
                        $mobileReadyScore = '';
                        $data['website'] = $url;

                        $url = 'http://'.$url;
                        $pageSpeedResult = $this->pageSpeedResult($url);


                        if( $pageSpeedResult['_metadata']['outcomeCode'] == 200 )
                        {
                            $pageSpeedData = $pageSpeedResult['records'];

                            $speedResult = json_encode($pageSpeedData['formattedResults']['ruleResults']);

                            $data['title_tag'] = $pageSpeedData['title'];
                            $data['page_speed_score'] = $pageSpeedData['score'];
                            $data['page_speed_suggestion'] = $speedResult;

                            $pageSpeedScore = $pageSpeedData['score'];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $speedResult = NULL;

                            $data['title_tag'] = NULL;
                            $data['page_speed_score'] = NULL;
                            $data['page_speed_suggestion'] = NULL;
                        }

                    $mobileFriendlyResult = NULL;

                    $data['mobile_ready_score'] = 0;
                    $data['mobile_ready'] = 0;
                    $data['mobile_ready_suggestion'] = NULL;

                    $data['google_analytics'] = 0;

                        Log::info("busnes " . $businessId);
                        Website::updateOrCreate(
                            ['business_id' => $businessId],
                            $data
                        );

                    $issueData = []
                        $thirdObj->globalIssueGenerator($userId, $businessId, '', $issueData, 'website', 'website');


                    return $this->helpReturn('Website data saved & issues are generated in system');
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::info(" getWebsiteDetails >> " . $e->getMessage());
            return $this->helpError(1, 'Some Problem happened to run script.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `$businessId`?

Comment: I've shortened the code to show here. business id is extract from token

Comment: I don't even know where is your token, so please include the part of the code where you assign `$businessId`

Comment: showing you wait

Comment: @Nikola I've edit and at bottom I've entered almost full of code which has necessary for this itme

Comment: $request->get('token') recevied from request like I'm sending this token from Postman to api
it extracts the user from database and then extract access of user linked business detail
then get businessId and other information

Comment: Can you verify that your `$businessId` is not null?

Comment: no all is good. no problem in business id

Comment: Are you sure? Can you double check?

Comment: logs list [2018-02-12 06:18:58] local.INFO: call   
[2018-02-12 06:19:03]: call   
[2018-02-12 06:19:16]: crossed external api point 4
[2018-02-12 06:19:16]: else 4
[2018-02-12 06:19:19]: crossed external api point 4
[2018-02-12 06:19:19]: else 4
------------------------------------------------------------
    [2018-02-12 06:59:56] local.INFO: call
    [2018-02-12 07:00:00] : call
    [2018-02-12 07:00:14] : crossed external api point 4
    [2018-02-12 07:00:14] : else
    [2018-02-12 07:00:17] : crossed external api point 4
    [2018-02-12 07:00:17] : if

Comment: @Nikola Yeah I'm 99.99% sure. 4 is business_id I've already checked If I've not business id program will terminate,                                                                           
                                                        // user selected business record is not found. 
                if($businessDetail['_metadata']['outcomeCode'] != 200)
                {
                    return $businessDetail;
                }'

Comment: One more thing If you look at attached screenshot then record is created along business_id and business_id is here foreign key and mandatory and it always insert along data

Answer (score 0):

Use [record locks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#pessimistic-locking) during the transaction to prevent duplicate records.

Locks can be applied at the table level - preventing any record from being modified - or at the record level - preventing any other processes from modifying just that record.

Since you have duplicates you'll likely need to use table level locking

Comment: I've multiple tables which I'm using transaction so you are referring convert Innodb to Myisam of all table? But no solution for Innodb?

Comment: looking at record locks.

Comment: Since you have duplicates you'll likely need to use table level locking? but don't understand why data is creating.                                                                
**when** data creation time before 3-5 seconds of next data creation. then why data re-inset like Transaction has not write the data yet which time shown in table? or how much time require to second request data has been inside the table so no need to create again?

Comment: Not sure If I've to add answer or edit my answer. but I add answer if I've to edit I'll del my answer

Answer (score 0):

@btl, @Nikola

Current I try with code location changes and returning result correctly and inserting record in database,

I paste out code from transaction which check data exist in database or not.
Currently I'm digging what's happening but I'm sharing the current status please see new code and old code. new code is working and also add logs of both code

Newcode after changing

```
public function getWebsiteDetails(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info("call ");
        try {

            /**
             * out from transction
             */
            // extract user 
            $checkPoint = $this->setCurrentUser($request->get('token'))->userAllow();

            $user = $checkPoint['records'];

            // extract business of user
            $businessDetail = $this->businessEntity->userSelectedBusiness($user);

            $businessDetail = $businessDetail['records'];
            $userId = $user['id'];
            $businessId = $businessDetail['business_id'];
            $url = $businessDetail['website'];

            /**
             * Get record from website_master of given business id
             */
            $businessWebsiteRecord = Website::where([
                'business_id' => $businessId
            ])->first();

            $result = DB::transaction(function () use($request, $url, $businessId, $userId,$businessWebsiteRecord)
            {
                $thirdObj = new ThirdPartyEntity();

                // if business_master (url) is exist then go to if block
                if ($url != '') {
                    $data = [];
                    $pageSpeedScore = '';
                    $mobileReadyScore = '';
                    $data['website'] = $url;
                    $url = 'http://' . $url;

                    $pageSpeedResult = $this->pageSpeedResult($url);

                    if ($pageSpeedResult['_metadata']['outcomeCode'] == 200) {
                        $pageSpeedData = $pageSpeedResult['records'];
                        $speedResult = json_encode($pageSpeedData['formattedResults']['ruleResults']);
                        $data['title_tag'] = $pageSpeedData['title'];
                        $data['page_speed_score'] = $pageSpeedData['score'];
                        $data['page_speed_suggestion'] = $speedResult;
                        $pageSpeedScore = $pageSpeedData['score'];
                    } else {
                        $speedResult = NULL;
                        $data['title_tag'] = NULL;
                        $data['page_speed_score'] = NULL;
                        $data['page_speed_suggestion'] = NULL;
                    }

                    $mobileFriendlyResult = NULL;
                    $data['mobile_ready_score'] = 0;
                    $data['mobile_ready'] = 0;
                    $data['mobile_ready_suggestion'] = NULL;
                    $data['google_analytics'] = 0;
                    Log::info("busnes " . $businessId);

                    $recordChecker = Website::where('business_id', $businessId)->first();

                    if (!empty($recordChecker)) {
                        Log::info("if busnes " . $businessId);
                    } else {
                        Log::info("else busnes " . $businessId);
                    }

                    Website::updateOrCreate(
                        ['business_id' => $businessId],
                        [
                            'website' => $url
                        ]
                    );
                    $issueData = [
                        [
                            'key' => 'title_tags',
                            'value' => $data['title_tag'],
                            'issue' => 36,
                        ],
                        [
                            'key' => 'page_speed',
                            'value' => $pageSpeedScore,
                            'issue' => 38,
                        ],
                        [
                            'key' => 'mobile_speed',
                            'value' => $mobileReadyScore,
                            'issue' => 37,
                        ],
                        [
                            'key' => 'google_analytics',
                            'value' => $data['google_analytics'],
                            'issue' => 39,
                        ]
                    ];
                    $thirdObj->globalIssueGenerator($userId, $businessId, '', $issueData, 'website', 'website');
                    return $this->helpReturn('Website data saved & issues are generated in system');
                }
            });

            Log::info("finish");
            return $result;

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::info(" getWebsiteDetails >> " . $e->getMessage());
            return $this->helpError(1, 'Some Problem happened to run script.');
        }
    }
```

Old code

```
public function getWebsiteDetails(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info("call ");
        try {
            return DB::transaction(function () use($request)
            {
                $thirdObj = new ThirdPartyEntity();

                // user extract
                $checkPoint = $this->setCurrentUser($request->get('token'))->userAllow();

                $user = $checkPoint['records'];
                $businessDetail = $this->businessEntity->userSelectedBusiness($user);

                $businessDetail = $businessDetail['records'];

                $userId = $user['id'];
                $businessId = $businessDetail['business_id'];
                $url = $businessDetail['website'];

                /**
                 * Get record from website_master of given business id
                 */
                $businessWebsiteRecord = Website::where([
                    'business_id' => $businessId
                ])->first();

                // if business_master (url) is exist then go to if block
                if ($url != '') {
                    $data = [];

                        $pageSpeedScore = '';
                        $mobileReadyScore = '';
                        $data['website'] = $url;

                        $url = 'http://'.$url;
                        $pageSpeedResult = $this->pageSpeedResult($url);


                        if( $pageSpeedResult['_metadata']['outcomeCode'] == 200 )
                        {
                            $pageSpeedData = $pageSpeedResult['records'];

                            $speedResult = json_encode($pageSpeedData['formattedResults']['ruleResults']);

                            $data['title_tag'] = $pageSpeedData['title'];
                            $data['page_speed_score'] = $pageSpeedData['score'];
                            $data['page_speed_suggestion'] = $speedResult;

                            $pageSpeedScore = $pageSpeedData['score'];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $speedResult = NULL;

                            $data['title_tag'] = NULL;
                            $data['page_speed_score'] = NULL;
                            $data['page_speed_suggestion'] = NULL;
                        }

                    $mobileFriendlyResult = NULL;

                    $data['mobile_ready_score'] = 0;
                    $data['mobile_ready'] = 0;
                    $data['mobile_ready_suggestion'] = NULL;

                    $data['google_analytics'] = 0;

                        Log::info("busnes " . $businessId);
                        Website::updateOrCreate(
                            ['business_id' => $businessId],
                            $data
                        );

                    $issueData = []
                        $thirdObj->globalIssueGenerator($userId, $businessId, '', $issueData, 'website', 'website');


                    return $this->helpReturn('Website data saved & issues are generated in system');
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::info(" getWebsiteDetails >> " . $e->getMessage());
            return $this->helpError(1, 'Some Problem happened to run script.');
        }
    }
```

Note: **Going in else because data not available in database so data will be create**
Going in If because data has already existed. (That' what I acquire)

**Ne code Logs**

```
[2018-02-12 14:18:49] local.INFO: call   
[2018-02-12 14:18:53] local.INFO: call
[2018-02-12 14:19:08] local.INFO: crossed external api point
[2018-02-12 14:19:08] local.INFO: else
[2018-02-12 14:19:08] local.INFO: finish
[2018-02-12 14:19:09] local.INFO: crossed external api point
[2018-02-12 14:19:09] local.INFO: if
[2018-02-12 14:19:09] local.INFO: finish
```

**Old Code Logs**

```
[2018-02-12 14:17:16] local.INFO: call   
[2018-02-12 14:17:19] local.INFO: call
[2018-02-12 14:17:34] local.INFO: crossed external api point
[2018-02-12 14:17:34] local.INFO: else
[2018-02-12 14:17:34] local.INFO: finish
[2018-02-12 14:17:35] local.INFO: crossed external api point
[2018-02-12 14:17:36] local.INFO: else
[2018-02-12 14:17:36] local.INFO: finish
```

**Currently as per old logs which run after first transaction**
that old code did not found record yet in database in second transaction but in new code logs shows
data before start second transaction found data in database,

Yeah this has the chance of failure but if the response is same and both call saving data at same time into database but I'll use another technique to handle this but New code has the better chances to track record if record already inserted 3-5 seconds ago which was failing on old code.

Thanks @btl and @Nikola. **But Please share if you have anything on this behavior.**